# SqlDataReader involving query with joins

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, performance, ado.net

I have 2 tables linked by a foreign Key (ID). In table1 there are 1 million records. In table 2 there are 50 million records.

I would like to read record from Table1 and read all the associated records of table 2.I can use `SqlDataReader` and implement `peek()` to implement this functionality as discussed here ([How do I implement a Peek() function on a DataReader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894165/how-do-i-implement-a-peek-function-on-a-datareader))

```
select ID, Col1 from Table1 order by ID

select ID, col2 from Table2 order by ID
```

But the downside of peek approach is I have to compare each child record with parent before advancing pointer of the parent result.

If I use join in SQL Server, it will perform join operation and then start streaming the result which requires a lot of memory.

Another approach would be to divide join operation in batches but this involved firing multiple SQL queries which I don't want..

Can you please suggest some alternative approach to achieve this?

Comment: You could work in pages, i.e. let the server perform the JOIN and request only rows with Table1 ID from 0 to 999. Then repeat the request for the next range, ... .

Comment: this is similar to batch solution which is not what i want..It will result in multiple queries to be fired..

Comment: Why do you assume the join method will require a lot of memory?  SqlDataReader will fill a few buffers as results are streamed and sued, but not as to consume significant memory.  It is only if you read the entire SqlDataReader results into a DataTable or similar object that a lot of memory will be used.

Comment: You're re-implementing a merge join. SQL Server handles that in constant memory, just like your app does.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you might want to look into using a partitioned table. [Here's the MySQL manual page on partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html), and [here's a Stack Overflow question that deals with partitioning and joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443588/mysql-partitioning-and-joins)

Comment: I am not sure if this would help because I don't have any where condition.. without where condition it will load all the partitions to apply the join condition..